# Axes.set_ylim overwrites previous command

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a subplot with different ratios. There is one slight problem with my code. The first plot has a limit on its y-axis between 150 and 250 and the second plot between 0 and 3. However, if I use the matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim command, it only takes into account the latest limit I've set. Since there is a big difference between the two, the result is far from what I anticipate.

Here is my code:

```
    N = 10
    ind = np.arange(N)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex='col', sharey=True, gridspec_kw= 
                            {'height_ratios': [2, 1]},  figsize=(16, 7))
    fig.set_tight_layout({'rect': [0, 0, 1, 0.95], 'pad': 1.5, 'h_pad': 1.5})
    plt.suptitle('Title')
    axes[0].bar(ind, mean_1990, color='gold')
    axes[0].plot(monthss, meanMonth[2:12], marker='o', color='tomato')
    axes[0].legend(['Monthly mean (1990 - 2020)', 'Mean values of 1990'])
    axes[0].errorbar(monthss, meanMonth[2:12], stdMonth[2:12], linestyle='None', marker='^', 
                     color='red')
    axes[0].set_ylim(150, 250)
    axes[0].set_ylabel('Area [km²]')
    axes[1].bar(monthss, amount1990, color='slateblue')
    axes[1].set_xticks(ind, ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
                       'August', 'September', 'October'))
    axes[1].get_ylim()
    axes[1].set_xlabel('Time')
    plt.show()
```

Hope someone would shed some light on the problem.

Comment: You have created the subplots with `sharey=True`. This makes both plots *share* the y-axis. As that isn't desired here, just leave out `sharey=True` (or set it to `False`)

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for the fast reply, it works like a charm!